# Prototypal Inheritance in Objects

Tags: javascript

I have a hamster object from which two hamsters inherit if i call eat on any one of them it writes to both hamsters.

```js
let hamster = {
  stomach: [],

  eat(food) {
    this.stomach.push(food);
  }
};

let speedy = {
  __proto__: hamster
};

let lazy = {
  __proto__: hamster
};

// This one found the food
speedy.eat("apple");
console.log( speedy.stomach ); // apple

// This one also has it, why?
console.log( lazy.stomach ); // apple
```

But searching i found solution that below code solves the problem. But didn't understand what's happening and how is prototypal inheritance actually working here.

```js
let hamster = {
  stomach: [],

  eat(food) {
    // assign to this.stomach instead of this.stomach.push
    this.stomach = [food];
  }
};

let speedy = {
   __proto__: hamster
};

let lazy = {
  __proto__: hamster
};

// Speedy one found the food
speedy.eat("apple");
console.log( speedy.stomach ); // apple

// Lazy one's stomach is empty
console.log( lazy.stomach ); // <nothing>
```

Above is the one which seems to be working by just replacing      `this.stomach.push(food);` with     `this.stomach = [food];`

Comment: The correct way to inherit is: `let speedy = Object.create(hamster)`. Even then, it will have the same behavior. If `stomach` property doesn't directly exist on the object, it will check it's [[Prototype]] which is the `hasmter` object and all the objects derived by `hasmter` will have the same `stomach` property. `this.stomach = []` will add a new `stomach` property directly on the `speedy` and `lazy` objects. So, in the second time, it doesn't need to look in the prototype chain and use the shared `hasmter.stomach` property

Comment: It's okay for object to have its own property stomach for each object but what if i have too many objects? Adding the same property on each and every object doesn't seem to be a good solution

Comment: If you want all the objects to have different `stomach`s, then they need to be directly on the object. That's why you need to use [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) for inheritance and creating new objects. Not an object literal

Comment: Got your point! but am trying to understand why the other solution works??

Comment: As I mentioned in the earlier comment, `this.stomach = []` will add a new `stomach` property directly on the `speedy` object. So, in the second time, it doesn't need to look in the prototype chain and use the shared `hasmter.stomach` property

Comment: Got from your first comment! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) page on prototype chains explains the issues. In the first code `stomach` doesn't exist in `speedy`, so the compiler searches the prototype chain.

One useful aspect of the code is that feeding `hamster` feeds all descendants in one go. No prototype chain is involved as `hamster` already has a stomach.

```js
let hamster = {
  stomach: [],

  eat(food) {
    // assign with spread operator to this.stomach instead of this.stomach.push
    this.stomach=[...this.stomach,food];
  }
};

let speedy = {
   __proto__: hamster
};

let lazy = {
  __proto__: hamster
};

// Feed the 'hamster'
hamster.eat("apple");

console.log( speedy.stomach ); // apple
console.log( lazy.stomach ); // apple

hamster.eat("carrot");

console.log( speedy.stomach ); // apple, carrot
console.log( lazy.stomach ); // apple, carrot
```